# php regex - need 2 groups captured

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need 2 groups captured: 1-expr (can be empty); 2-essi

see code below

```
$s = 'regular expr<span>essi</span>on contains';
function my_func($matches){

    //I need 2 groups captured
    //$matches[1] - "expr" (see $s before span) - can be empty, but I still need to capture it
    //$matches[2] - "essi" (between spans)
}
$pattern = "???";
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, my_func, $s);
```

Comment: Well, I have already answered, but I shouldn't encourage this, so there is still this question: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = "~(\w*)<span>(\w+)</span>~";
```

This should do the trick.

If the second group should be able to match empty strings as well, replace the `+` by another `*`. Note that `\w` will match letters, digits and underscores. If that is too much or insufficient, replace it by an appropriate character class.

One more thing: I think the syntax for `preg_replace_callback` requires you to hand in the function name as a string.

Comment: I thought I try to rephrase my question - I think I delete this q. Sorry for your wasted time.

Comment: @Jeffz What do you mean rephrase? Is this not what you were actually looking for?

Comment: @Jeffz :if your question is the same, but clarified and rephrased then *just edit the question* (click the 'edit' link below your question's tags), don't delete it; that's incredibly discourteous to those who took the time to try and help you. Clearly explain your problem, explain what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: @Jeffz if you are referring to my comment on the question. I didn't mean to be rude. I just wanted to point out that it's common courtesy on Stack Overflow to explain what you've tried (with over 400 rep you probably already know that anyway). But I thought, in any case it would increase the value of your question a lot if you still included that info. And it would also decrease the likeliness of others downvoting it.

Comment: @m.buettner I did not take it this way ... it is late here and I'm a bit tired

Comment: @David Thomas you are right - I should have done that - SO is choking enough on unanswered/repetitive Q's - I should not have added to the list